# Unable to run app if I debug the app before in Device or Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-debug

I have debugged the app with device and emulator but I unable to run the app on that device or emulator.

Studio version : 3.5.2

And It's display like below screenshot when I run the app.

[image]

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait untill debugger attach to your connected device. If you facing some issue while attaching debuger please attach that issue.

Comment: actually I ran the application and I waited too much of time too but it's not attched

Comment: make sure you device is not offline. Try to run on another emulator or real device.

Comment: yes my device is in online and again If I debug it's works fine